# How do I do AVX vector blending with clang native vector syntax (no intrinsics)?

Tags: c, clang, simd, conditional-operator, avx512

To my delight, I found that clang will let you write explicit vector code, without resorting to intrinsics, using [extended vectors](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors).

For instance, this code:

```
typedef float floatx16 __attribute__((ext_vector_type(16)));

floatx16 add( floatx16 a, floatx16 b )
{
    return a+b;
}
```

...will translate directly to a single instruction with `clang -march=skylake-avx512` invocation:

```
vaddps  zmm0, zmm0, zmm1
```

In order to write branch-free code, I want to blend avx512 vectors.
With intrinsics, you would use the `_mm512_mask_blend_ps` intrinsic. *(By the way, why is does AVX512 use mask,a,b order, and AVX use a,b,mask order?)*

Trying to do the blend with the ternary operator does not work:

```
typedef float floatx16 __attribute__((ext_vector_type(16)));

floatx16 minimum( floatx16 a, floatx16 b )
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

...results in...

```
error: used type 'int __attribute__((ext_vector_type(16)))' (vector of 16 'int' values) where arithmetic or pointer type is required
```

Is it possible to do [vector blending](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#cats=Swizzle&expand=457,451,451&text=_mm512_mask_blend_ps), `vblendmps zmm {k}, zmm, zmm`, using **ext_vector_type(16)** variables in C?

Comment: why don't you want to use intrinsics and why don't you use an avx framework/library?

Comment: `float16` is a very confusing type name.  Most people would expect that to mean a scalar 16-bit half-precision float.  Perhaps `floatx16`?  As for your actual question, IDK, clang might well be able to optimize some manual compare + AND/ANDN/OR blend into a compare + blend instruction, with scalar autovectorization or with GNU C / clang native vectors.  (Or better, a `vaddps` with merge-masking, depending on what you're blending into.)

Comment: If you used `vector_size` instead, you'd get nicely vectorized code for both gcc and clang: https://godbolt.org/z/a73TG3

Comment: @bolov because `a+b-c` is a lot more legible than `_mm256_sub_ps( _mm256_add_ps(a,b), c)` and the fewer frameworks, the better.

Comment: @chtz Awesome! If you write it up, I'll accept that as the answer. Bonus pts if you can briefly touch upon the difference between them, and why there are two?

Comment: @bolov intrinsics work with only a single architecture whereas vector code works with x86, ARM, PowerPC... automatically

Comment: The gcc version of these vector extensions only supports `?:` in c++, not c. I don't know whether the clang implementation is compatible in this regard, because I refuse to use it, since it uses a gratuitously incompatible syntax for shuffles, so for any non-trivial vector code it is wholly incompatible for no good reason at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is the comment by @chtz in answer-form:)

**There are at least two different ways to do vector types:**

*Form A:*

**__attribute__ ( ( ext_vector_type(numelements) ) );**

*Form B:*

**__attribute__( ( vector_size(numbytes) ) );**

When using form A, the expression `c ? x : y` will cause a compile error with clang 11.

Worse than that, gcc 10 will just silently pretend that ext_vector_type(N) has 4 elements even if N is 8 or 16.

When using form B, the expression `c ? x : y` is [properly translated](https://godbolt.org/z/conhEj) into a vector blend by clang 11. Clang 10 and gcc 10 translate it into something different though, but they are both able to compile it.

It is unclear to me why the ext_vector_type form exists, especially considering how badly it works.

### UPDATE 1

Ugh... this only works in C++ but not in C. **WHY???**

### UPDATE 2

The difference in behaviour is [in the specification](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#id1).

Comment: `ext_vector_type` was originally a clang thing, I didn't know GCC supported it at all.  I don't know what it was for, though, that you couldn't already do with `vector_size`

Comment: @PeterCordes What a mess... I found out that this only works in C++ not in C. Ugh... back to intrinsics it is, then.